# How to modify the main query to show ACF fields

Tags: query

I have this code but the main query is preventing all ACF fields being displayed on the front end...

```
// Add a new admin menu item for the options page
function my_plugin_add_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'User Category Settings',
        'User Categories',
        'manage_options',
        'user_categories',
        'my_plugin_options_page'
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_add_admin_menu');

// Create the options page content
function my_plugin_options_page() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Save the selected category for each user
    if (isset($_POST['user_category_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['user_category_nonce'], 'user_category')) {
        $user_ids = get_users(array('fields' => 'ID'));
        
        foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
            if (isset($_POST['category_' . $user_id])) {
                $category = $_POST['category_' . $user_id];
                update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_category', $category);
            }
        }
        
        echo '<div class="notice notice-success"><p>Categories saved successfully.</p></div>';
    }
    
    // Display the options form
    $user_ids = get_users(array('fields' => 'ID'));
    
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h1>User Category Settings</h1>';
    echo '<form method="post">';
    wp_nonce_field('user_category', 'user_category_nonce');
    
    foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
        $user = get_user_by('ID', $user_id);
        $selected_category = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_category', true);
        
        echo '<h3>' . $user->display_name . '</h3>';
        
        $categories = get_categories();
        echo '<select name="category_' . $user_id . '">';
        echo '<option value="">Select a category</option>';
        
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $selected = ($selected_category == $category->term_id) ? 'selected' : '';
            echo '<option value="' . $category->term_id . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $category->name . '</option>';
        }
        
        echo '</select><br><br>';
    }
    
    echo '<input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Categories">';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
}

// Modify the main query to restrict posts based on user's category
function my_plugin_restrict_posts_by_category($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        $user_category = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'user_category', true);
        
        if ($user_category) {
            $query->set('cat', $user_category);
        } else {
            // Redirect the user to the front page if no category is assigned
            wp_redirect(home_url());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_plugin_restrict_posts_by_category');



// Check post category on single post view and redirect if necessary
function my_plugin_check_post_category2() {
    if (is_single() && is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID());
        $user_category = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'user_category', true);
        
        if (!in_array($user_category, $post_categories)) {
            wp_redirect(home_url());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_plugin_check_post_category2');
```

Comment: I doubt this will fix the issue, but if the intent is to modify only the main query, then need to check that `pre_get_posts` is running on the main query: add `$query->is_main_query()` to your `if` statement.